# Show the Lagrange equations can also be written on Nielsen's form

Tags: classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

Show that the Lagrange Equations can also be written on [Nielsen's form](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/NielsensForm.html)

$$\frac{\partial \dot{T}}{\partial \dot{q}_j} - 2\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_j}=Q_j.$$

Comment: Showing us your working/thoughts might help.

Answer (score 5):

The total time derivative is
$$ \frac{d}{dt}~=~\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\dot{q}^j\frac{\partial}{\partial q^j}+\ddot{q}^j\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}^j}+\dddot{q}^j\frac{\partial}{\partial \ddot{q}^j}+\ldots, \tag{1}$$

where dot denotes time differentiation.
Hence the commutator between a velocity differentiation and total time differentiation is a position differentiation

$$ \left[  \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}^j},\frac{d}{dt}\right]
~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~ \frac{\partial}{\partial q^j}.\tag{2}$$

In particular,

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}^j}
~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~ 
\frac{\partial\dot{T}}{\partial \dot{q}^j}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q^j},\tag{3}$$

where $T(t,q,\dot{q})$ is the kinetic energy.
The Lagrange equations read

$$ Q_j~=~\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}^j}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q^j}~\stackrel{(3)}{=}~  \frac{\partial\dot{T}}{\partial \dot{q}^j}-2\frac{\partial T}{\partial q^j}, \tag{4}$$
where $Q_j$ is the generalized force.

*A note on terminology:* It is customary to only refer to Lagrange equations (4) as [*Euler*-Lagrange equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) if they arise from a [variational principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action). This is the case if there exists a [generalized potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_system) $U(t,q,\dot{q})$ for the generalized forces $Q_j$.

Answer (score 1):

so, Here is the Solution to your Question.
(Please click on Image to view it clearly)
[image]

Comment: I know this is an old tread but I'm doing this problem now and I'm stuck at the last line on page 2 - in particular because I don't understand how the second-to-last term deltaT/deltaq_j appear?